# adjust visualization parameters as parametric values

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, statistics, visualisation, parameters

i want to define visualization parameters for maps as codes in main coding space not as import record

for this, i want to calculate the min and max values of image and set them in visualization parameters

i wrote such a code:

```
var Rectangle = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
       [[[30.733619384765614,37.77441684925436],
       [30.9471661376953,37.77441684925436],
       [30.9471661376953,37.92135417196918],
       [30.733619384765614,37.92135417196918],
       [30.733619384765614,37.77441684925436]]], null, false);

var Aster = ee.ImageCollection("ASTER/AST_L1T_003"),
var Asterbands =['B01','B02','B3N','B04','B05','B06','B07','B08','B09','B10','B11','B12','B13','B14']

Map.setOptions('HYBRID');    
Map.centerObject(Rectangle)

//+++++++++++++++\\

var AsterImageMosaic= (Aster
        .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2021-11-01')
        .select(Asterbands))
        .mosaic().clip(Rectangle)

print(AsterImageMosaic)

Map.addLayer(AsterImageMosaic,{},'Aster Image Mosaic')


//+++++band ratio function+++++\\

var Aster_EVI2=AsterImageMosaic.expression(
  '2.5 * (Aster_3N - Aster_B02) / (Aster_3N + 2.4 * Aster_B02 - 1)',{
    'Aster_3N' : AsterImageMosaic.select('B3N'),
    'Aster_B02' : AsterImageMosaic.select('B02')
  });
Map.centerObject(Rectangle);

//+++++++
print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform for EVI:', Aster_EVI2.projection());
print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform for Aster:', AsterImageMosaic.projection());
```

as the problem in projections i could not able to calculate the min and max values of Aster_EVI2 thus i use the following code to get stat for Aster_EVI2 image (im not sure that is true or not):

```
var affine = [0.00026949458523585647, 0, -180, 0, -0.00026949458523585647, 86.0000269494563];

var EVI_Min=Aster_EVI2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry: Rectangle,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  crsTransform: affine,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

var EVI_Max=(Aster_EVI2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: Rectangle,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  crsTransform: affine,
  maxPixels: 1e9
})).values()

var EVIMin= EVI_Min.get(0)
var EVIMax= EVI_Max.get(0)

print('EVI_Min',EVI_Min)
print(ee.Number(EVIMax))
var EVIVisParam = {
  min: -0.5,
  max: 0.8,
  palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301']
}

Map.addLayer(Aster_EVI2, EVIVisParam, 'Aster EVI');
```

but i want to apply such coding for visualization parameters so that automatically min max values be utilized in mapping:

```
var EVIVisParam = {
  min: EVI_Min,
  max: EVI_Max,
  palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301']
}
```

is there any for such adjustments?
here is the code scripts:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2FSolmaz%2FBurdur_Sentinel_CloudFree%3ATest

Answer (score 0):

You can use them in `Image.visualize` before adding the result to the map.  You just plug the visualization parameters (with the computed values) into visualize, exactly like you're trying to do with Map.addLayer:

```
var EVIVisParam = {
  min: EVI_Min,
  max: EVI_Max,
  palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301']
}

Map.addLayer(Aster_EVI2.visualize(EVIVisParam), {}, 'Aster EVI');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4835e1695798d0d363c105bf99d12eaf

Comment: but how? as i mentioned            var EVIVisParam = {
  min: EVI_Min,
  max: EVI_Max,
  palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301']
}            does not work